# How to fix incorrect forum post count when using internalization and locale?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, nodes

Using (among several other contrib modules)

- Forum
- Locale
- Advanced Forum
- Internationalization

My forum topic nodes are set to be localized and I've set translations for the Forum Vocabulary and all the terms. The forums work well with Internationalization after I modified some of the views and added a 'Content: Language (= Current user's language)' filter.

However the Topics count in the main forum page is incorrect, it doesn't take into account the language, so we  see a higher count than we should.

For example:
https://freshwaterwatch.thewaterhub.org/forum

The 'Meet & Greet' forum has five topics but when you enter you only see two topics: https://freshwaterwatch.thewaterhub.org/forums/meet-and-greet

What happens is that if you click on the French language you see one and two more in the Spanish language, that's why the count for the forum is 5 but you should instead see a count of 2 when browsing the site in the default english language.

Does anyone know how to solve this or a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [advanced_forum_statistics_topics](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/advanced_forum/advanced_forum.module/function/advanced_forum_statistics_topics/5) (check your `advanced_forum` version)

```
return db_result(db_query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(nid)) FROM {forum}'));
```

You can use preprocess [forum_statistics](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/advanced_forum/advanced_forum.module/function/advanced_forum_preprocess_advf_forum_statistics/5) and instead of `advanced_forum_statistics_topics();` use your own function to select only nids which relate to the current language.

Comment: Can you give me an example function please?

Comment: what is your advanced forum version?

Comment: I'll give you the bounty because its about to end but please remember to give me an example, thanks.